# IonInput losing autofocus

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement an input with the `autofocus` attribute, it is working when I'm using it alone, but when I add an IonButton it's not working.

This is my code, I removed all of the unnecessary code to simplify the question:

```
import { IonContent, IonPage, IonInput, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonInput autofocus></IonInput>

        <IonButton size="default" className="btn center" type="submit">
          Login
        </IonButton>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Why is that?, the button needs to be of type `submit` because it's inside a form

**Edit**

I also tried with `<input type="submit">` and it worked, but it also fails with `<input type="button">` and I would like to use it.